# Cognos Reports - How set icons on control objects?

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

Recently I've started to create some active reports and I'm having some troubles to put a icon into my data control objects. I mean the icon on the picture below:

[image: Data tab control]

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognos is expecting a list of URLs to images in this case. Be sure to use the full URL, not relative ([see IBM doc](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21648018)). Data-driven means it needs to come from a database, not be hard-coded.

I'd also suggest bookmarking [the official IBM Active Reports cookbook](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/reporting/active_report/page593-pdf.pdf) for reference.